# Converting exponents to CSV using excel and C++

Tags: c++, excel, csv, localization

I'm trying to write a CSV file, and I have a value which is 6.49483e-005, that's written correctly in the CSV, but it doesn't display correctly in the excel. it reads as 6,48E+00.

I'm doing that in C++, if you want, you can ask for code, I'm using long double for the value that is written to the CSV and then convert it to string, then write it.

```
s = "00043E61"
digitstring = "00000000000001000011111001100001"
sum = 6.4753228798508644e-005
n = 278113
```

in CVS it's `6.49483e-005`

in excel :

[image]

```
            stringstream ss;
            ss << hex << s;
            unsigned n;
            ss >> n;
            bitset<32> b(n);
            string digitstring = b.to_string();

             if(digitstring[0] == '1')
             {
                negative = true;

             }
             long double sum = 0; 
             int exp = 1;
             int v = 0;
             if(negative)
             {
                v = 1;
             }
             else
             {
              v = 0;
             }
             for(; v < digitstring.size(); v++)
             {
             int b = digitstring[v] - '0';
             long double result = (long double)b/power(2,exp);
             sum+=result;
             exp = exp +1;


             }
            if(negative)
            {
                sum*=-1;
            }
             ostringstream os;
             os << sum;
             resultsSoil.push_back(os.str());
         }
```

Comment: Yes, always code please! :)  --- But if it's written correctly in the CSV, it's probably the display format of the cell.  In Excel, hit Ctl+1 and change Format to Scientific with 6 digits of precision.  See if that does it.

Comment: it is still read as 6,494830E+00. however in CSV it's written as 6.49483e-005

Comment: OK - I may be misunderstanding.  Please further edit your question to show the input `unsigned n` value, the corresponding `sum` and `os.str()` values, the bytes in the CSV file, and a screenshot of what Excel shows when you open the CSV.  (PS building your own `double`s is pretty hard-core :) .)  Thank you!

Comment: See what locale Excel is using.  Looks like Excel is printing using "," as digit separator.

Comment: @cxw I have updated the question, with results of the code, and an image of the excel

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have looked at Excel locale, but where is "," as digit separator ? where is it exactly in excel. Thanks a lot

Comment: I can import the CSV value correctly on a US-English locale.  I think @ThomasMatthews is probably right about the locale affecting the import.  Try putting just `6.49483e-005` *and nothing else* into a file called `test.csv`, and then opening that in Excel.  If it doesn't work, try a `.csv` file including `"6,49483e-005"` (with quotes) and nothing else.  Hopefully one of those will work.  (PS - why doesn't `sum` match what's in the CSV?)

Comment: @cxw The quotes did the trick! Thanks a lot

Comment: @cxw make it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ThomasMatthews pointed out, your locale doesn't use `.` as a digit separator.  Therefore, you need to format your numbers the way Excel is expecting them.  Plus, commas in a CSV file need to be enclosed in double-quotes.  Format your numbers as `"6,49483e-005"` before you output them to the CSV and you should be OK!